# User Model with a foreign key and primary key?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom User Model that is setup as

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

field1 = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique = True, primary_key = True)
field2 = models.CharField(max_length=5)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'field1'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"
```

I have several additional models that relate to the primary key field1, the relationship works great.

My problem is adding an existing database table which primary key is field2 in my user model.

```
class ModelWantingToRelateOnField2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column='field2',primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
    max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Table2'
```

When I add the one to one my vizgraph data model shows it's trying to relate on field1, when I need the relationship to occur for field2 on this model and all my others relate on field1.

I've tried using ForeignKey and also related_name, but after migration the model tries to relate on field1.

When trying to load table2 prior to my User model I get the following SQL error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There are no primary
 or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Table2' that match the referencing column list in the foreign ke
y 'user_field2_id_8e77ca93_fk_Table2_Field2'. (1776) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

The model in question when it's flipped with ModelWantingToRelateOnField2/FacilityDimension first:

```
class FacilityDimension(models.Model):
    unit_num = models.CharField(db_column='Unit_Num', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    company_code = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Code', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    coid = models.CharField(db_column='Coid',primary_key=True, serialize=False, max_length=5, unique = True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    coid_name = models.CharField(db_column='COID_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    c_level = models.CharField(db_column='C_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    company_name = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    s_level = models.CharField(db_column='S_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sector_name = models.CharField(db_column='Sector_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    b_level = models.CharField(db_column='B_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    group_name = models.CharField(db_column='Group_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    r_level = models.CharField(db_column='R_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    division_name = models.CharField(db_column='Division_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    d_level = models.CharField(db_column='D_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    market_name = models.CharField(db_column='Market_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    f_level = models.CharField(db_column='F_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cons_facility_name = models.CharField(db_column='Cons_Facility_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lob_code = models.CharField(db_column='LOB_Code', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lob_name = models.CharField(db_column='LOB_Name', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sub_lob_code = models.CharField(db_column='Sub_LOB_Code', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sub_lob_name = models.CharField(db_column='Sub_LOB_Name', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    state_code = models.CharField(db_column='State_Code', max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_id_current = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_ID_Current', max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_current_name = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Current_Name', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_id_future = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_ID_Future', max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_future_name = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Future_Name', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_7_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_7_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_8_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_8_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_phys_svc_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Phys_Svc_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_asd_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_ASD_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_imaging_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Imaging_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_oncology_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Oncology_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_cath_lab_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Cath_Lab_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_intl_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Intl_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_other_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Other_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_coid = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_COID', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_status = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Status', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    company_code_operations = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Code_Operations', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    osg_pas_ind = models.CharField(db_column='OSG_PAS_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    abs_facility_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='ABS_Facility_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    abl_facility_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='ABL_Facility_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    intl_pmis_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='INTL_PMIS_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hsc_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='HSC_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    loaddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='LoadDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Facility_Dimension'


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):



    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_cfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    officename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positioncode = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.ForeignKey(FacilityDimension, max_length=5)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

#    REQUIRED_FIELDS = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s %s' % (self.username, self.first_name, self.last_name)


class QvDatareducecfo(models.Model):
    cfo_fname = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_FName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cfo_lname = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_LName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cfo_ntname = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,db_column='CFO_NTName',max_length=11, primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cfo_type = models.IntegerField(db_column='CFO_Type', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    org_level_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Org_Level_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    org_level = models.CharField(db_column='Org_Level', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    unit_no = models.CharField(db_column='Unit_No', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dr_code = models.CharField(db_column='DR_Code', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dr_name = models.CharField(db_column='DR_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cfo_dr_code = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_DR_Code', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cfo_dr_name = models.CharField(db_column='CFO_DR_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    b_level = models.CharField(db_column='B_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    group_name = models.CharField(db_column='Group_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'QV_DataReduceCFO'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cfo_ntname)





class QvReportList(models.Model):
    qv_dept_id = models.CharField(db_column='QV_Dept_ID', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_id = models.CharField(db_column='Report_ID',primary_key=True, max_length=100, serialize=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name_sc = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name_SC', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qv_filename = models.CharField(db_column='QV_FileName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_access = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Access', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_sub_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Sub_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approver_fname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_FName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approver_lname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_LName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approver_ntname = models.CharField(db_column='Approver_NTName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    approval_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Approval_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    role_based_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Role_Based_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'QV_Report_List'


class QVReportAccess(models.Model):
    user_status = models.CharField(db_column='User_Status', max_length = 20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ntname = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,db_column='NTName', max_length=11,primary_key=True, serialize=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_name_sc = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Name_SC', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    datareduce_report_code = models.IntegerField(db_column='DataReduce_Report_Code', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    role_based_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Role_Based_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_id = models.OneToOneField(QvReportList,db_column='Report_ID', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Report_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_access = models.CharField(db_column='Report_Access', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sr_datareduce_summary_code = models.CharField(db_column='SR_DataReduce_Summary_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sr_datareduce_patient_code = models.CharField(db_column='SR_DataReduce_Patient_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    userid = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    user_group_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='User_Group_ID', blank=True, null=True)
    access_level_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Access_Level_ID', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)
    qv_statusid = models.IntegerField(db_column='QV_StatusID', blank=True, null=True)
    employee_status_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Employee_Status_ID', blank = True, null = True)
    new_user = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_User', blank = True, null = True)
    new_access = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_Access', blank = True, null = True)
    new_report = models.IntegerField(db_column='New_Report', blank = True, null = True)
    changed_row = models.IntegerField(db_column='Changed_Row',blank = True, null = True)
    last_change_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Last_Change_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    access_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Access_Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    access_end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Access_End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Report_Beg_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Report_End_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qv_startdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='QV_StartDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'QV_ReportAccess'

class QVFormAccessRequest(models.Model):
    ntname = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    datareducecode = models.CharField(max_length=2500)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    report_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    accesslevel_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phi = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    access_beg_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    access_end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'QV_FormAccessRequest'





class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'

class Sysdiagrams(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    principal_id = models.IntegerField()
    diagram_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    version = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    definition = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sysdiagrams'
        unique_together = (('principal_id', 'name'),)
```

Here is my makemigration after deleting all django tables:

```
WARNINGS:
accounts.User.coid: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.
        HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model DjangoMigrations
    - Create model FacilityDimension
    - Create model QvDatareducecfo
    - Create model QVReportAccess
    - Create model QvReportList
    - Create model Sysdiagrams
PS C:\python\security> python manage.py makemigrations
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
accounts.User.coid: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.
        HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts\migrations\0002_qvformaccessrequest_user.py
    - Create model User
    - Create model QVFormAccessRequest
```

Here is the error message when running migrate:

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
accounts.User.coid: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.
        HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying accounts.0001_initial... OK
  Applying accounts.0002_qvformaccessrequest_user...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 545, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'F
acility_Dimension' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'user_coid_id_8e77ca93_fk_Facility_Dimension_Coid'. (1776) (SQLExecDirectW)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_lin
e
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 93, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\schema.py", line 604, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HFA9592\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 545, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced
 table 'Facility_Dimension' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'user_coid_id_8e77ca93_fk_Facility_Dimension_Coid'. (1776) (SQLExecDir
ectW)")
```

Comment: It sounds like you might need the [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) option. Note that you can't use it as a one-to-one field unless `User.field2` has `unique=True`.

Comment: User.field2 won't be unique because there are multiple users at one facility.

Comment: Either I don't understand your question, or you're trying to do something that won't work. You can't have a one-to-one field that refers to `User.field2` if `User.field2` isn't unique.

Comment: The field2 is unique for each user.  Perhaps I misunderstood, but multiple users will have the same coid.  I originally used foreign_key instead of OneToOneField.

Comment: Table2 is just a dimension table, that has a only one coid/field2.  Each User should only have one coid, there may be an instance where an employee does have two coids, but only one primary.

Comment: I added the error I get when moving the table2 prior to User.

Comment: Please don't mix made up names like `ModelWantingToRelateOnField2` with actual error messages. It makes it harder to see what's going on.

Comment: I corrected the error message to relate to the example, this is just what happens when I tried to load the table WantingToRelateOnField2 prior to my User model.  Ideally the user model should load first, but nothing I try seems to allow me to create the relationship on field2.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by loading one model before the other. To go back to my original comment, if `ModelWantingToRelateOnField2.field2` is the same as `User.field2`, then you want to use `to_field`. However this won't work if `User.field2` does not have `unique=True`.

Comment: Doesn't unique True mean that all users will have a unique coid and no two users can have the same?  I can't be the only one who wants to relate another dimension to my user model on a different key than the primary?

Comment: You aren't the only person who wants that. That's why there's a `to_field` option that I keep on mentioning. However, if two users have `coid='abcde'`, then you can't use `to_field='coid'` in your `OneToOneField`, since the `coid` doesn't uniquely identify a user.

Comment: What can I use?  I'm not trying to use the coid to uniquely identify a user, I want to uniquely identify a facility per user.  Which is what the coid does.

Comment: I don't understand. Your question doesn't mention `facility` anywhere.

Comment: coid is unique to a facility.  in my example the user model is pulled from Active Directory and each User has a coid that identifies a facility.  The table2 is the dimension which includes all information about a coid/field2.  The table2 doesn't include anything to relate to an individuals id.

Comment: It sounds like you've got your relationship the wrong way round, and it should be `User` that has a foreign key to the related model.

Comment: I tried that as well, but I get the SQL error above, i'm guessing it has something to do with managed = false and there not being any cardinality built into that table..

Comment: You haven't shown the code or schema that causes that error so it's impossible to help.

Comment: It's mentioned above, I can make the migrations, but when I run migrate that's what causes the error.  It's in the model above because if I switch the order back it runs fine.

Comment: I'll try one last time. Your models in your question do not make sense. It sounds like the foreign key should be on the `User` model. If that gives an error, then you need to show the actual models, actual schema and actual error, otherwise I can't help any more.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that i'm explaining what i'm trying that's failing in several scenarios.  I attached the code with the FacilityDimension that runs prior to the User model with the foreign key in the User model.  Also, beneath that is the makemigrations and then the migrate error.

Comment: You shouldn't get the error message `accounts.User.coid: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True` since you did not set `unique=True` when you did `coid = models.ForeignKey(FacilityDimension, max_length=5)`.

Comment: You have `primary_key=True`, `unique=True` for `FacilityDimension.coid`, but is that really the case in the database table?

Comment: In the database the coid is unique for every row in the Facility_Dimension table.  There is no designated primary key in the database.  Perhaps if I remove the primary_key = True and use your suggestion for to_field = 'coid'.

Comment: Doing what mentioned above doesn't work, it gives the same error shown above.  Looks like i'll have to work with my friends dad to have them add the primary key/ candidate key.

Comment: You might be able to avoid the error if you set [`db_constraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint) to `False` for the foreign key, but performance will be better if you add the primary key.

Comment: That did it.  If you write an answer showing to switch the order of the models, add to_field = 'coid', and db_constraint = False for the foreign key I can mark it correct.  I appreciate you Alasdair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like multiple users can have the same `FacilityDimension`. Therefore you should have a foreign key on the `User` model, not on `FacilityDimension`.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    coid = models.ForeignKey('FacilityDimension', db_constraint=False)
```

Django will be unable to create the foreign key constraint if the primary key/unique index does not exist on the target model. You can prevent Django from creating the constraint by setting [`db_constraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint).

You shouldn't have to re-order your models if you use a string `'FacilityDimension'` instead of the class `FacilityDimension`.

You shouldn't need to set `to_field`, because the foreign key is pointing to the `FacilityDimension.coid` field which has `primary_key=True`.